# SwiftUI NavigationView in VStack

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

I have the following code:

**First Struct:**

```
struct MenuButton: View {

    var buttonText: String
    var buttonCallView: AnyView

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: self.buttonCallView) {
                Text(self.buttonText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Struct:**

```
struct ProfileMenuContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            MenuButton(buttonText: "Settings", buttonCallView: AnyView(SettingsView()))
            MenuButton(buttonText: "My Favourites", buttonCallView: AnyView(MyFavouritesView()))
            MenuButton(buttonText: "Sign Out", buttonCallView: AnyView(SignOutView()))
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following behaviour:
[image: if]

**What I want:**
When one button gets pressed, rather then just taking the 1/3th of the space for the new View it should take the fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your wanted behavior, all you have to do is remove the NavigationView from inside the MenuBotton struct and add a NavigationView to your ProfileMenuContent.

new code:

```
struct MenuButton: View {

    var buttonText: String
    var buttonCallView: AnyView

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: self.buttonCallView) {
            Text(self.buttonText)
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileMenuContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                MenuButton(buttonText: "Settings", buttonCallView: AnyView(SettingsView()))
                MenuButton(buttonText: "My Favourites", buttonCallView: AnyView(MyFavouritesView()))
                MenuButton(buttonText: "Sign Out", buttonCallView: AnyView(SignOutView()))
            }
        }
    }
}
```